# Oracle Apex error ORA-01776: cannot modify more than one base table through a join view

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an app in Oracle Apex 22.21. There are multiple tables (`ORDERS`, `ORDER_ITEMS`, `STORES`, and `PRODUCTS`).

- `ORDERS` table
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZWci.png)

I have a **Master Detail** report that is editable. The main report shows the `ORDERS` table and the detail shows the `ORDER_ITEMS` table.

- Report image
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhNiP.png)

In the `ORDERS` table, there is a column `STORE_ID` which is a foreign key to the `STORES` table. The `STORES` table has a column `STORE_NAME`. I am able to edit the report (change the `STORE_ID` to another 'id' ex: 1,2,3) when the table's **Source** is set to the `ORDERS` table.

- `STORES` table
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wix4e.png)
- `STORES` table data
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agZfm.png)

I want the `ORDERS` table to include the `STORE_NAME` column referring to the `STORES` table. As it does not make sense for the user to enter a `STORE_ID` to edit a row. I want the user to be able to edit the `STORE_ID` by entering the `STORE_NAME` or by choosing an **LOV**. I changed the report **Source Type** to **SQL Query** and ran the below code.

```
 select 
    ORDERS_LOCAL.*,
    STORES.STORE_NAME
from ORDERS_LOCAL
inner join STORES
ON ORDERS_LOCAL.STORE_ID=STORES.STORE_ID
```

However, when I try to edit a cell, I encounter an error `ORA-01776: cannot modify more than one base table through a join view`

I've found a [post/solution](https://blogs.ontoorsolutions.com/post/apex-forms-reloaded-part-2/) regarding this error and tried to follow the instructions. The first solution does not work in my case because I actually want the user to be able to edit the `STORE_ID` column by showing `STORE_NAME`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX6Dp.png)

I've tried changing and running the PL/SQL code exactly as instructed but nothing saves when I change a cell value and click save. But I don't receive any error.

```
BEGIN
   CASE :apex$row_status
      WHEN 'C'
      THEN
         INSERT INTO stores (store_id, store_name)
              VALUES ( :p10_store_id, :p10_store_name);
         INSERT INTO orders_local (order_id,
                          order_number,
                          order_date,
                          store_id,
                          full_name,
                          email,
                          city,
                          state,
                          zip_code,
                          credit_card,
                          order_items
                          )
              VALUES ( :p10_order_id,
                      :p10_order_number,
                      :p10_order_date,
                      :p10_store_id,
                      :p10_full_name,
                      :p10_email,
                      :p10_city,
                      :p10_state,
                      :p10_zip_code,
                      :p10_credit_card,
                      :p10_order_items);
      WHEN 'U'
      THEN
         UPDATE orders_local
            SET order_id = :p10_order_id,
                order_number = :p10_order_number,
                order_date = :p10_order_date,
                store_id = :p10_store_id,
                full_name = :p10_full_name,
                email = :p10_email,
                city= :p10_city,
                state= :p10_state,
                zip_code= :p10_zip_code,
                credit_card= :p10_credit_card,
                order_items= :p10_order_items
          WHERE order_id = :p10_order_id;
         UPDATE stores
            SET store_name = :p10_store_name
          WHERE store_id = :p10_store_id;
      WHEN 'D'
      THEN
         DELETE orders_local
          WHERE order_id = :p10_order_id;
         DELETE stores
          WHERE store_id = :p10_store_id;
   END CASE;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a step back. The "report that is editable" is an interactive grid. If the report is display only, then you can use any SQL to display data. However, if it is editable then the SQL statement is used to update the rows as well. The statement

```
 select 
    ORDERS_LOCAL.*,
    STORES.STORE_NAME
from ORDERS_LOCAL
inner join STORES
ON ORDERS_LOCAL.STORE_ID=STORES.STORE_ID
```

Cannot be used to update the store_id in the orders_local table. Currently you're trying to work around this by using custom code for the update but that is overcomplicating things. So, take a step back and restart.

1. The query for the interactive grid should be

```
 select 
    *
from ORDERS_LOCAL
```

2. Define a List of Values to display the select list for Stores. The query for that list of values is

```
 select 
    store_id as return_value,
    store_name as display_value
from stores
```

In the interactive grid us this list of values for the store_id column.

That is all there is to it. This will allow you to use the native process for handling the IG updates.